# How to prevent api being called multiple times on scroll controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a scroll controller. I am making a request when the scroll position passes a defined value. The problem is, it is making thousands of requests when it overpasses the position. To prevent this I tried implementig a loading but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my scroll controller

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    PetsBloc petsBloc = BlocProvider.of<PetsBloc>(context);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      final ScrollPosition position = _scrollController.position;
      if (position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent - 500 &&
          selectedView.isNotEmpty &&
          !petsBloc.state.loading) {
        //* Make the requeset
        petsBloc.add(CollectionRequested(collection, page));
        setState(() {
          page++;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

This is my `pets_bloc.dart`:

```
class PetsBloc extends Bloc<PetsEvent, PetsState> {
  PetsRepository petsRepository = PetsRepository();
  AlertsRepository alertsRepository = AlertsRepository();
  InfoRepository infoRepository = InfoRepository();

  PetsBloc() : super(const PetsState()) {
    on<CollectionRequested>((event, emit) async {
      if (!state.loading) {
        emit(state.copyWith(loading: true));
        final List<PetModel> result =
            await petsRepository.getCollection(event.collection, event.page * 10);
        switch (event.collection) {
          case 'lost':
            emit(state.copyWith(lostPets: [...state.lostPets, ...result]));
            break;
          case 'transit':
            emit(state.copyWith(foundPets: [...state.foundPets, ...result]));
            break;
          case 'adoption':
            emit(state.copyWith(adoptionPets: [...state.adoptionPets, ...result]));
            break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is my `pets_state.dart`

```
part of 'pets_bloc.dart';

class PetsState extends Equatable {
  final List<PetModel> lostPets;
  final List<PetModel> adoptionPets;
  final List<PetModel> foundPets;
  final List<AlertModel> alertPets;
  final List<UserPost> userPosts;
  final bool loading;
  final bool fetched;

  const PetsState({
    this.lostPets = const [],
    this.adoptionPets = const [],
    this.foundPets = const [],
    this.alertPets = const [],
    this.userPosts = const [],
    this.loading = false,
    this.fetched = false,
  });

  PetsState copyWith({
    List<PetModel>? lostPets,
    List<PetModel>? adoptionPets,
    List<PetModel>? foundPets,
    List<AlertModel>? alertPets,
    List<UserPost>? userPosts,
    bool? loading,
    bool? fetched,
  }) =>
      PetsState(
        lostPets: lostPets ?? this.lostPets,
        adoptionPets: adoptionPets ?? this.adoptionPets,
        foundPets: foundPets ?? this.foundPets,
        alertPets: alertPets ?? this.alertPets,
        userPosts: userPosts ?? this.userPosts,
        loading: loading ?? this.loading,
        fetched: fetched ?? this.fetched,
      );

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [lostPets, adoptionPets, foundPets, alertPets, userPosts];
}
```

The request is still being made even though I have an if with `petsBloc.state.loading` in my initstate and inside the on an `if(!state.loading)`

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you seeing any log for api is getting called or loading is showing always?

Comment: lots of api calls. Loading is triggered but still making requests so I assume there's a problem inside the initstate if()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_infinite_list/lib/posts/bloc/post_bloc.dart) you could find an official example of how to throttle your events so that only a single event will be fired in a short period.

The main idea is to implement a custom event transformer:

```
EventTransformer<E> throttleDroppable<E>(Duration duration) {
  return (events, mapper) {
    return droppable<E>().call(events.throttle(duration), mapper);
  };
}
```

Notice, that you need to add a `bloc_concurrency` package to your project dependencies.

Then, use this event transformer in your bloc:

```
class PetsBloc extends Bloc<PetsEvent, PetsState> {
  PetsRepository petsRepository = PetsRepository();
  AlertsRepository alertsRepository = AlertsRepository();
  InfoRepository infoRepository = InfoRepository();

  PetsBloc() : super(const PetsState()) {
    on<CollectionRequested>((event, emit) async {
      if (!state.loading) {
        emit(state.copyWith(loading: true));
        final List<PetModel> result =
            await petsRepository.getCollection(event.collection, event.page * 10);
        switch (event.collection) {
          case 'lost':
            emit(state.copyWith(lostPets: [...state.lostPets, ...result]));
            break;
          case 'transit':
            emit(state.copyWith(foundPets: [...state.foundPets, ...result]));
            break;
          case 'adoption':
            emit(state.copyWith(adoptionPets: [...state.adoptionPets, ...result]));
            break;
        }
      }
    },
    transformer: throttleDroppable(Duration(milliseconds: 100)), // Use the new transformer
    );
  }
}
```

At the moment, all of the events within 100 milliseconds will be dismissed and only a single event will be fired. Feel free to adjust this duration value based on your needs.